# Multiple Replace excel VBA vba

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

- FIND | REPLACE
- Apple | Date
- Apricot | Boysenberry
- Avocado | Cloudberry
- Banana | Coconut
- Bilberry | Blackcurrant
- Blackberry | Cranberry
- Blackcurrant | Blackberry
- Blueberry | Apricot
- Boysenberry | Cherimoya
- Cantaloupe | Cherry
- Currant | Dragonfruit
- Cherry | Currant
- Cherimoya | Durian
- Cloudberry | Damson
- Coconut | Banana
- Cranberry | Apple
- Damson | Avocado
- Date | Blueberry
- Dragonfruit | Bilberry
- Durian | Cantaloupe

I USED MANY VBA CODE BUT FAIL

Comment: So, what do you want to do? Do you want to find something and replace that with another thing?

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you are able to get your table above into two columns in Excel (using Data to Columns, pipe delimiter).  You can run this macro and it'll go line by line, getting a find/replace set, and replace that over column B.  Naturally, change the search range as necessary.

```
Sub find_Replace()
Dim lastRow&, i&
Dim sFind$, sReplace$
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Range("D:D")

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming your data is in cols A and B

For i = 2 To lastRow
    With searchRange
        sFind = Trim(Cells(i, 1))
        sReplace = Trim(Cells(i, 2))
        .Replace what:=sFind, replacement:=sReplace
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Edit: this won't work as is because it'll replace "banana" with coconut correctly, buy then change that replacement back to "banana" later... I'll try to fix in a bit.

Comment: "A" is data---------"B" is finding date--------"C" is Replace date

Comment: @ryguy72 - thanks, except it's not quite complete I must admit.  I'll see if I can get some time to make sure nothing gets overwritten (see my edit comment in my answer).